# A script to convert flac files to wav is not working

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have the following script

```
 #!/bin/bash

for dir in /home/marius/data/LibriSpeech/train-clean-100/*/*
do
    for file in "$dir"/*
    do
        if [[ -f $file ]]
            then
            $name=$(echo $filename | cut -f 1 -d '.')
            ffmpeg -i $file $name.wav
            rm $file 
        fi
done
done
```

Basically I want to descend 2 subdirectories deep in the train-clean-100 folder and change all .flac files to .wav, then delete the .flac files.

Somehow this is not working.

Comment: Can you tell us what does not work? If you call the script by `bash -x <script>` it may give you more hints. One thing that is obvious: To define a variable (`name`in this case), you must not preceed it with `$`. And to avoid problems with dots in your path, you should do `name=$dir/$(basename $file .flac)`. And if there are other files there (except .flac), you should do `for file in $dir/*.flac`. And you could even better use `find`to get the files you want to convert.

Comment: @Rahul `file` is not a `bash` builtin.  Which isn't to say it should be used as a variable name though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As ridgy said, I suggest using find to get the files you want to convert:

```
#!/bin/bash

folder=/home/marius/data/LibriSpeech/train-clean-100

for file in $(find "$folder" -type f -iname "*.flac")
do
    name=$(basename "$file" .flac)
    dir=$(dirname "$file")
    echo ffmpeg -i "$file" "$dir"/"$name".wav
    #ffmpeg -i $file $dir/$name.wav
    #rm $file
done
```

Also use quotes when expanding variables for possible problems with whitespaces, and for this kinds of scripts check with echo if it does what you want before executing.

Comment: This one does what I want except for not removing the original .flac files. I tried with rm $file , does not seem to work.

Comment: nevermind, it works